# How to Find the Recurrence Formula for $\int \frac{dx} {(1+\sin x)^n}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{dx} {(1+\sin x)^n}$$

I know that I should use the following step:

> $$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)\, dx}{(1+\sin x)^n} +\int\frac{\cos^2(x)\, dx} {(1+\sin x)^n} $$

but here I get stuck. I do not know how shall I proceed.

Comment: Have you tried the [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)?

Comment: Yes i did,but,unfortunately i got nowhere.

Comment: Were you given limits, or is this an indefinite integral?

Comment: It is an indefinite integral.

Comment: Substitute $x=y+\pi/2$, use $1+\cos y=2\cos^2(y/2)$, and integrate by parts to develop a recuurence relationship for $\int \sec^{2n}(y/2)\,dy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more direct method exists without substitution, which I will discuss here.

Observe that:

$\displaystyle \large 2I_n - I_{n-1} = \int \frac{\cos^2{x}}{(1+\sin{x})^{n+1}} \text{d}x = \int \frac{\text{d}(1+\sin{x})}{(1+\sin{x})^{n+1}} \cos{x}$

Integrate by parts directly to obtain:

$\displaystyle \large 2I_n - I_{n-1} = -\frac{\cos{x}}{n(1+\sin{x})^n} - \frac{1}{n} \int \frac{\sin{x}}{(1+\sin{x})^n} \text{d}x$

$\displaystyle \large 2I_n - I_{n-1} = -\frac{\cos{x}}{n(1+\sin{x})^n} - \frac{I_{n-1}-I_n}{n}$

Rearrange to obtain:

$\displaystyle \large (2n-1)I_n = -\frac{\cos{x}}{(1+\sin{x})^n} + (n-1)I_{n-1}$

And the rest is trivial.

Comment: There is a fatal flaw in the first step of this development.  Note that  $2I_n-I_{n-1}=\int \frac{1-\sin(x)}{(1+\sin(x))^n}\,dx\ne \int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{(1+\sin(x))^n}\,dx$$

Comment: I've edited to correct the exponent in the first line of the development.  It's interesting to see that $$-\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+\sin(x))^n}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sec^{2n-2}(x/2-\pi/4)\tan(x/2-\pi/4)$$is an identity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_n$ be the sequence given by the integral

$$I_n=\int \frac{1}{(1+\sin(x))^n}\,dx \tag 1$$

First, we enforce the substitution $x=2y+\pi/2$ into $(1)$ to obtain

$$I_n=\int \frac{2}{(1+\cos(2y))^n}\,dy \tag 2$$

Noting that $1+\cos(2y)=2\cos^2(y)$, we write $(2)$ as

$$I_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\int \sec^{2n}(y)\,dy$$

Next, we integrate by parts with $u=\sec^{2n-2}(y)$ and $v=\tan(y)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\left(\sec^{2n-2}(y)\tan(y)-(2n-2)\int \sec^{2n-2}(y)\tan^2(y)\,dy \right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\left(\sec^{2n-2}(y)\tan(y)-(2n-2)2^{n-1}I_n+(2n-2)2^{n-2}I_{n-1} \right)\\\\
&=\frac{n-1}{2n-1}I_{n-1}+\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}(2n-1)}\right)\,\sec^{2n-2}(x/2-\pi/4)\tan(x/2-\pi/4)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that I was the first to post a solution and had posted a comment almost one year ago that outlined this way forward.  -;))

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark